# $\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}3^n(z+1)^n$ convergence radius

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Find the convergence radius of the following series $$\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}3^n(z+1)^n$$

All the exercises I solved of this sort, the series were in the following form $\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$.

If I apply the same formula for convergence I get the following:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n}{3^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{3}$

So I would the say the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{3}$ and the domain for convegence would be the disc $B(1,\frac{1}{3})$ centered at $1$ and not at $0$.

**Questions**:

Is the disc $B(1,\frac{1}{3})$ the convergence domain?
My intuition tells me the disc is $B(1,\frac{1}{3})$. Is it correct? If so, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The center is at $z=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as the power series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (3z+3)^n$$
which is well known to converge when
$$|3z+3|\lt 1$$
$$|z+1|\lt\frac13$$
So $z$ is any complex number within the circular locus centred at $-1$ with radius $\frac13$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you explain me the reason behind the change of centre of the disc changes from 0 to another point? What is the proof behind it? I am not finding it.

Comment: Well the inequality $|z+1|\lt\frac13$ defines a locus which is in fact a circle radius $\frac13$ centred at $-1$. One can prove this by using $z=x+iy$ and finding a Cartesian equation of the locus.

Comment: Could you please expand how should I prove the statement please?